# CfnCloudFormationProduct syntax issues in aws-cdk

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-service-catalog

I am trying to create a service catalog product using a cloudformation template with aws-cdk. My template has already been created and stored in s3. Here is the sample code I am using for doing this

```
template_location = "".join(["https://s3.amazonaws.com/", S3_RESOURCES_BUCKET, "/", "template.json"])

sc.CfnCloudFormationProduct(scope, "SCProduct", name="SCProduct", owner="",
                                    provisioning_artifact_parameters=[{"info": {"loadTemplateFromUrl": template_location}}])
```

I am receiving this error when I am trying to synthesize:
`jsii.errors.JSIIError: No stack could be identified for the construct at path SCProduct`

What am I doing wrong here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `scope` you need to pass the stack object, usually it's `self`.